# How do I import mp3agic library to Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This is the library: https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic

It mentions something about maven and building but I have no clue what that means.  I've been looking up tutorials on importing libraries to Intellij and none of what I tried worked.  I tried importing from Maven but all I get is a `pom.xml` file and that's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no idea about Maven or Gradle, go to File, Project Structure, Modules, select Dependencies tab and click on green "+" and select .jar of the library you downloaded.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html

Comment: @EdinMujakic wait, there's supposed to be a .jar file?  The git repository just has the code to the library.

Comment: If you have .jar file you can use first method, I would strongly advise you to read a bit on Maven and understand how to add dependencies, it's really not that hard, it's a matter of copying a few lines and pasting them inside your pom.xml file.

Comment: I've already done that.  The pom.xml file has the dependency info that is listed on github.  But what am I supposed to do with that file?  How does that file give me access to the library?  Am I supposed to build a .jar file out of the github code?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  I was using wrong way of importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realized I was importing from Maven incorrectly.  For those that are curious, I went to Maven central and found the library.  Before I wasn't able to find it because I was inputting the incorrect coordinates.

For mp3agic it's: `com.mpatric : mp3agic : 0.9.1`.  In Intellij you just go

File > Project Structure > Libraries > '+' > From Maven

and search the coordinate listed above.  Once found, choose the version you want to use, import, and apply!